# Checking whether a function is a potential CDF

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a real-valued random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Consider the function $F(x)$ with  $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow  [0,1]$. One way to show that $F$ can be a candidate cumulative distribution function of $X$ is to show that it is

(i) increasing

(ii) right continuous

(iii) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}F(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0$

If and only if these three conditions are satisfied, we might have $X$ distributed as $F$ and $F(x):=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega) \in (-\infty, x]\})$

---

Suppose we are given instead the function $G(B)$ with $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $G:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,1]$ for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel sigma algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we find that $G$ can be a probability measure on the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e.

(a) $G(B)\geq 0$  $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

(b) $G(\emptyset)=0$

(c) $G(\mathbb{R})=1$

(d) For any $\{B_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $B_i \cap B_j=\emptyset$ $\forall i \neq j$ $G(\cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B_i)=\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}G(B_i)$

This means that we might have $G(B):=\mathbb{P}(X \in B)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega) \in B\})$ for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, included $B=(-\infty, x]$, which implies that $G$ can be a candidate cumulative distribution function of $X$.

> Question: are the two ways of proceeding equivalent? My doubt is due
>   to the fact that the set of conditions (i)-(iii) is different from the
>   set of conditions (a)-(d).

Comment: $G$ is a function on the Borel sigma algebra giving a measure for open sets, whereas $F$ is a function on real numbers giving a measure for half open intervals. But since the Borel sigma algebra can be generated by open or by half open intervals, the induced measures are equivalent.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about the fact that in the second procedure I'm not checking for right continuity, monotonicity, etc?

Comment: Monotonicity follows from a) and d). Right-continuity should also follow from d) using set algebra (approaching the half open interval with intersections of open intervals).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $F(x) = G( (-\infty, x])$ is a cumulative distribution function by the usual arguments ($G(\mathbb{R}) = 1, G(\emptyset) = 0$, monotonicity of measure for increasing-ness and continuity of measure for right continuity) which you can check.

$G$ itself is not a CDF -- its defined on B(R), not R.

Comment: "its defined on B(R), not R": I don't understand, isn't $(-\infty, x]$ a subset of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? If we consider only the $B=(-\infty. x]$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then we obtain $G((-\infty,x]):=\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$. Isn't this a cdf by definition?

Comment: $G$ is a function on $B(\mathbb{R})$. A CDF is a function on $\mathbb{R}$. The function $F(x) = G( ( -\infty, x])$ is a CDF, but $G$ is not.